# How to redirect shortcuts in start menu side bar?

Tags: windows-explorer, hyperlink

This set of folder shortcuts on the left of the Start menu
by default searches `C:/Users/_username_/` for folders like music, photos, and documents:

[image]

I have a very limited C: drive though, so I store these files externally, in `D:/Users/_username_/`.

How do I break the news to these shortcuts that the folders they're looking for are gone and they need to move on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To move any of those folders (and let Windows know about it):

- Open Explorer
- Navigate to `C:\Users\username`
- Right-click on the folder to move and select Properties
- Switch to the Location tab
- Enter manually the new folder, or click "Move..." to select a folder
- Click OK
- In the confirmation dialog:

  - Click Yes to create the new location and move all your files from
    the old location
  - Click No to create the folder but not to move your current files.

The documentation doesn't specify what happens if the new location folder
already exists, so be careful, in case some version of Windows decides
to delete the existing new folder.

Comment: Thank you sir! Can confirm it only copies the contents of the current location to the new folder. It doesn't overwrite anything

Comment: I was..? I was saying i already did it and I can confirm in case anyone else was wondering. I made a backup, left all the original files there to see what would happen to them, and then executed your instructions. No files were overwritten

Comment: So everything works now. Wonderful.